# Calculating stats for single band raster using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

In the QGIS script editor, how do I calculate the main stats (minimum, maximum, mean, median, standard deviation,....) for a single band raster?

I am trying to make a tool for extracting a MASK (0-1) to cover clouds and cloud shadows for Landsat imagery. The algorithm is based on the 'MEAN' and 'Standard Deviation' of Bands BLUE and NIR. To do this I wrote the following script using the 'script editor' within 'Script' tool into the Processing Toolbox of the QGIS. Indeed the script works well, but I would like to automatically calculate 'MEAN' and 'Standard Deviation' instead of entering the values manually.

---

```
 ##Shadow-Cloudless MASK=name 
 ##BLUE=raster 
 ##NIR=raster 
 ##MeanBLUE=number 0.0 
 ##StDevBLUE=number 0.0 
 ##MeanNIR=number 0.0 
 ##StDevNIR=number 0.0 
 ##StDevDivisionFactorBLUE=number 1.0 
 ##StDevDivisionFactorNIR=number 1.0 
 ##MASK=output raster

 from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry 
 import numpy as np

 #Get layer object
 layer1 = processing.getObject(BLUE)

 #Get layer object
 layer2 = processing.getObject(NIR)

 #Get number
 number1 = MeanBLUE

 #Get number
 number2 = StDevBLUE

 #Get number
 number3 = MeanNIR

 #Get number
 number4 = StDevNIR

 #Get number
 number5 = StDevDivisionFactorBLUE

 #Get number
 number6 = StDevDivisionFactorNIR

 def mask (BLUE,NIR,MeanBLUE,StDevBLUE,MeanNIR,StDevNIR,StDevDivisionFactorBLUE,StDevDivisionFactorNIR,output):
    entries=[]

    #define raster 1 ("BLUE")
    raster1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    raster1.ref='BLUE@1'
    raster1.raster=BLUE
    raster1.bandNumber=1
    entries.append(raster1)

    #define raster 2 ("NIR")
    raster2=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    raster2.ref='NIR@1'
    raster2.raster=NIR
    raster2.bandNumber=1
    entries.append(raster2)

    number1='MeanBLUE'
    number2='StDevBLUE'
    number3='StDevDivisionFactorBLUE'
    number4='MeanNIR'
    number5='StDevNIR'
    number6='StDevDivisionFactorNIR'

    #MASK Processing
    calc=QgsRasterCalculator('((("BLUE@1"<('+str(MeanBLUE)+'+('+str(StDevBLUE)+'/'+str(StDevDivisionFactorBLUE)+')))+("NIR@1">('+str(MeanNIR)+'-('+str(StDevNIR)+'/'+str(StDevDivisionFactorNIR)+'))))=' + str(2) + ')',output,'GTiff',NIR.extent(),NIR.width(),NIR.height(),entries)
    calc.processCalculation()

mask(layer1,layer2,number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6,MASK)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
ext = layer.extent()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,ext,0)

print "minimum value = ", stats.minimumValue
print "maximum value = ", stats.maximumValue 
print "mean = ", stats.mean
print "stdDev = ", stats.stdDev
```

---

Here it is running from the **Script Editor**:

[image: Script Editor]

---

**EDIT**:

I've modified your script and ran it through the *Processing Toolbox* which worked. It was tested it on a sample raster and an output was generated so hopefully it will work for you:

```
##Shadow-Cloudless MASK=name 
##BLUE=raster 
##NIR=raster 
##StDevDivisionFactorBLUE=number 1.0 
##StDevDivisionFactorNIR=number 1.0 
##MASK=output raster

from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry 
from qgis.core import QgsRasterBandStats
import numpy as np

#Get layer object
layer1 = processing.getObject(BLUE)

#Get layer object
layer2 = processing.getObject(NIR)

#Get band statistics of layer1
provider1 = layer1.dataProvider()
ext1 = layer1.extent()
stats1 = provider1.bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,ext1,0)

#Get band statistics of layer2
provider2 = layer2.dataProvider()
ext2 = layer2.extent()
stats2 = provider2.bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,ext2,0)

#Get number
number1 = stats1.mean

#Get number
number2 = stats1.stdDev

#Get number
number3 = stats2.mean

#Get number
number4 = stats2.stdDev

#Get number
number5 = StDevDivisionFactorBLUE

#Get number
number6 = StDevDivisionFactorNIR

def mask (BLUE,NIR,MeanBLUE,StDevBLUE,MeanNIR,StDevNIR,StDevDivisionFactorBLUE,StDevDivisionFactorNIR,output):
   entries=[]

   #define raster 1 ("BLUE")
   raster1=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
   raster1.ref='BLUE@1'
   raster1.raster=BLUE
   raster1.bandNumber=1
   entries.append(raster1)

   #define raster 2 ("NIR")
   raster2=QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
   raster2.ref='NIR@1'
   raster2.raster=NIR
   raster2.bandNumber=1
   entries.append(raster2)

   number1='MeanBLUE'
   number2='StDevBLUE'
   number3='StDevDivisionFactorBLUE'
   number4='MeanNIR'
   number5='StDevNIR'
   number6='StDevDivisionFactorNIR'

   #MASK Processing
   calc=QgsRasterCalculator('((("BLUE@1"<('+str(MeanBLUE)+'+('+str(StDevBLUE)+'/'+str(StDevDivisionFactorBLUE)+')))+("NIR@1">('+str(MeanNIR)+'-('+str(StDevNIR)+'/'+str(StDevDivisionFactorNIR)+'))))=' + str(2) + ')',output,'GTiff',NIR.extent(),NIR.width(),NIR.height(),entries)
   calc.processCalculation()

mask(layer1,layer2,number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6,MASK)
```

Comment: Actually it works perfectly within the python console of the QGIS, but not for the Script Editor, which is what I am looking for. Any solution?

Comment: @Nico_77 - Huh, works fine for me in the Script Editor. Do you receive any errors? Did you select the raster when you ran it?

Comment: it gives me the following message in the log: name 'qgis' is not defined

Comment: Try adding `import qgis` at the beginning.

Comment: Not yet, now the message is:name 'QgsRasterBandStats' is not defined.

Comment: At any rate maybe it is better to explain the whole objective. Actually I am trying to make a tool for extracting a MASK to cover clouds and cloud shadows for Landsat imagery. To do this I wrote the following script:

Comment: Try also adding `from qgis.core import QgsRasterBandStats`. You should perhaps [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/191535/edit) your question to include your objective as not a lot of people read through the comments. This way, others can also hopefully help :)

Comment: You **really** need to put that in your question =)

Comment: The idea is to work with thresholds of MEAN and StDEV, but instead of entering the values manually, I would like to use stats calculation instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39026/discussion-between-nico-77-and-joseph).

Comment: I've edited my post =)

Comment: Joseph, the script as you have edited works perfectly!! It is Amazing. Thanks a lot. I just found a little discrepancy between the resulting stats and the stats reported into the properties of the raster, although the only value which is really different is the MINIMUM....do you know why?

Comment: STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0.0065747760236263
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.13608266213896
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.18396917439112

Min Val=0.0033619697
Max Val=1.0000000000
Mean=0.1359672027
Standard Deviation=0.1831130846

Comment: Take into account that I am working with Landsat Imagery with the background set as No-DATA instead of zero

Comment: @Nico_77 - Most welcome! Hmm I think the differing values can be described by this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58809/min-and-max-values-are-not-correctly-calculated-for-dem/58858#58858) when it comes to using the Properties window for the raster. If you want a more accurate calculation of statistics, you can use `Raster > Miscellaneous > Information` instead.

Comment: That is ok. Indeed within the "Style box" into the properties window, if you set "Min/max" and the Accuracy to "Actual(slower)" instead of "Estimate(faster)" the values of the basics stats are the same!! GREAT!!

Comment: @Nico_77 - Awesome, glad your problem is finally solved ;)