# Reprojecting raster changes pixel scale (makes it darker)

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, sar

I have an HH polarised SAR image as follows:

[image: SAR_4326]

This is how it looks in QGIS in the default EPSG:4326 projection.

Now I would like to reproject this raster to ESRI:102020 (South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection). I can do this fine on QGIS and it looks as follows:

[image: SAR_102020]

This is fine. However when I try to do the same via `gdalwarp`

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -of GTiff s1a-ew-grd-hh-20200317t225506-20200317t225606-031721-03a873-001.tiff reproj.tiff
```

The reprojected raster is much darker as shown below:

[image]

Now its clear this is due to the scaling of the pixel values in the reprojection (0 to 4454 -> 0 to 15561). Why is this happening? To be more precise why is it that reprojecting in QGIS does **not** change the scale of pixel values whereas using gdalwarp (to do the same operation) does.

Following is the output of: `gdalinfo s1a-ew-grd-hh-20200317t225506-20200317t225606-031721-03a873-001.tiff`

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: s1a-ew-grd-hh-20200317t225506-20200317t225606-031721-03a873-001.tiff
Size is 17114, 16217
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection = 
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,298.2572235604902,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0,0) -> (-51.9954921915471,-63.8957637448199,-8.30739736557007e-06)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (856,0) -> (-51.6000130781883,-63.815715063168,-7.20564275979996e-06)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (1712,0) -> (-51.2067866490764,-63.7345909047409,-6.34975731372833e-06)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (2568,0) -> (-50.8158212163499,-63.6524011044357,-5.67175447940826e-06)
GCP[  4]: Id=5, Info=
          (3424,0) -> (-50.4271244774541,-63.5691556256142,-5.11948019266129e-06)
GCP[  5]: Id=6, Info=
          (4280,0) -> (-50.0407035573213,-63.4848642668803,-4.66778874397278e-06)
GCP[  6]: Id=7, Info=
          (5136,0) -> (-49.6565645825152,-63.3995370021001,-4.2840838432312e-06)
GCP[  7]: Id=8, Info=
          (5992,0) -> (-49.2747128896954,-63.3131837931561,-3.96557152271271e-06)
GCP[  8]: Id=9, Info=
          (6848,0) -> (-48.8951531243128,-63.2258145292834,-3.68990004062653e-06)
GCP[  9]: Id=10, Info=
          (7704,0) -> (-48.5178892986398,-63.137439000881,-3.44961881637573e-06)
GCP[ 10]: Id=11, Info=
          (8560,0) -> (-48.1429244814785,-63.0480671835066,-3.24379652738571e-06)
GCP[ 11]: Id=12, Info=
          (9416,0) -> (-47.7702611312136,-62.9577089448684,-3.06125730276108e-06)
GCP[ 12]: Id=13, Info=
          (10272,0) -> (-47.3999010780518,-62.8663740661883,-2.89641320705414e-06)
GCP[ 13]: Id=14, Info=
          (11128,0) -> (-47.0318453355864,-62.774072407619,-2.75112688541412e-06)
GCP[ 14]: Id=15, Info=
          (11984,0) -> (-46.6660943012677,-62.6808137472396,-2.62446701526642e-06)
GCP[ 15]: Id=16, Info=
          (12840,0) -> (-46.3026477202025,-62.5866078306573,-2.50525772571564e-06)
GCP[ 16]: Id=17, Info=
          (13696,0) -> (-45.9415047735077,-62.4914643201849,-2.3944303393364e-06)
GCP[ 17]: Id=18, Info=
          (14552,0) -> (-45.5826639164266,-62.3953929451095,-2.29757279157639e-06)
GCP[ 18]: Id=19, Info=
          (15408,0) -> (-45.2261230682344,-62.2984033501513,-2.20630317926407e-06)
GCP[ 19]: Id=20, Info=
          (16264,0) -> (-44.8718794886445,-62.2005051720615,-2.12900340557098e-06)
GCP[ 20]: Id=21, Info=
          (17113,0) -> (-44.5227987861975,-62.1025193496058,-2.04984098672867e-06)
GCP[ 21]: Id=22, Info=
          (0,811) -> (-52.1641268544205,-63.7279283255242,-8.2729384303093e-06)
GCP[ 22]: Id=23, Info=
          (856,811) -> (-51.7705596488955,-63.6482918290304,-7.17397779226303e-06)
GCP[ 23]: Id=24, Info=
          (1712,811) -> (-51.37920636884,-63.5675853730759,-6.32274895906448e-06)
GCP[ 24]: Id=25, Info=
          (2568,811) -> (-50.9900754118974,-63.4858186348724,-5.64660876989365e-06)
GCP[ 25]: Id=26, Info=
          (3424,811) -> (-50.6031746536178,-63.4030013513872,-5.09805977344513e-06)
GCP[ 26]: Id=27, Info=
          (4280,811) -> (-50.2185112216204,-63.3191432787758,-4.64357435703278e-06)
GCP[ 27]: Id=28, Info=
          (5136,811) -> (-49.8360913880597,-63.2342542320574,-4.26638871431351e-06)
GCP[ 28]: Id=29, Info=
          (5992,811) -> (-49.4559207819494,-63.1483438993856,-3.94508242607117e-06)
GCP[ 29]: Id=30, Info=
          (6848,811) -> (-49.0780042190134,-63.0614220281417,-3.67313623428345e-06)
GCP[ 30]: Id=31, Info=
          (7704,811) -> (-48.7023458049096,-62.9734983497484,-3.43751162290573e-06)
GCP[ 31]: Id=32, Info=
          (8560,811) -> (-48.328948804408,-62.8845827047516,-3.22703272104263e-06)
GCP[ 32]: Id=33, Info=
          (9416,811) -> (-47.957816112128,-62.7946846312314,-3.04728746414185e-06)
GCP[ 33]: Id=34, Info=
          (10272,811) -> (-47.5889495486489,-62.7038139842191,-2.88244336843491e-06)
GCP[ 34]: Id=35, Info=
          (11128,811) -> (-47.2223505703829,-62.6119803199962,-2.73901969194412e-06)
GCP[ 35]: Id=36, Info=
          (11984,811) -> (-46.8580198546566,-62.5191932686744,-2.60677188634872e-06)
GCP[ 36]: Id=37, Info=
          (12840,811) -> (-46.4959572969994,-62.425462547937,-2.49128788709641e-06)
GCP[ 37]: Id=38, Info=
          (13696,811) -> (-46.136162451155,-62.3307976164,-2.38418579101562e-06)
GCP[ 38]: Id=39, Info=
          (14552,811) -> (-45.7786340773243,-62.2352080696662,-2.286396920681e-06)
GCP[ 39]: Id=40, Info=
          (15408,811) -> (-45.4233703525527,-62.1387034666748,-2.19140201807022e-06)
GCP[ 40]: Id=41, Info=
          (16264,811) -> (-45.0703690536836,-62.0412931603116,-2.11410224437714e-06)
GCP[ 41]: Id=42, Info=
          (17113,811) -> (-44.7224862047334,-61.9437940834308,-2.03680247068405e-06)
GCP[ 42]: Id=43, Info=
          (0,1622) -> (-52.3308693139328,-63.5599100150093,-8.23289155960083e-06)
GCP[ 43]: Id=44, Info=
          (856,1622) -> (-51.9391987359374,-63.4806804095238,-7.14045017957687e-06)
GCP[ 44]: Id=45, Info=
          (1712,1622) -> (-51.5497041627202,-63.4003863542306,-6.29294663667679e-06)
GCP[ 45]: Id=46, Info=
          (2568,1622) -> (-51.1623940759476,-63.3190373631339,-5.62053173780441e-06)
GCP[ 46]: Id=47, Info=
          (3424,1622) -> (-50.7772764394267,-63.2366430238614,-5.07477670907974e-06)
GCP[ 47]: Id=48, Info=
          (4280,1622) -> (-50.394358496716,-63.1532129356531,-4.62587922811508e-06)
GCP[ 48]: Id=49, Info=
          (5136,1622) -> (-50.0136466645894,-63.0687567494222,-4.2477622628212e-06)
GCP[ 49]: Id=50, Info=
          (5992,1622) -> (-49.6351467195353,-62.9832840036005,-3.9292499423027e-06)
GCP[ 50]: Id=51, Info=
          (6848,1622) -> (-49.2588636473071,-62.8968042931141,-3.65730375051498e-06)
..........
a whole lot of GCPs
..........
GCP[435]: Id=436, Info=
          (12840,16216) -> (-49.8147518977658,-59.3194238597005,-2.23796814680099e-06)
GCP[436]: Id=437, Info=
          (13696,16216) -> (-49.4795876491336,-59.2329471172809,-2.13459134101868e-06)
GCP[437]: Id=438, Info=
          (14552,16216) -> (-49.1461224280091,-59.1456118480941,-2.04611569643021e-06)
GCP[438]: Id=439, Info=
          (15408,16216) -> (-48.8143582979236,-59.057425332999,-1.96322798728943e-06)
GCP[439]: Id=440, Info=
          (16264,16216) -> (-48.4842969041853,-58.9683948252967,-1.88499689102173e-06)
GCP[440]: Id=441, Info=
          (17113,16216) -> (-48.158617675307,-58.8792657886883,-1.81421637535095e-06)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:03:18 05:05:15
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=Sentinel-1A EW GRD HR L1
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Sentinel-1 IPF 003.20
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,16217.0)
Upper Right (17114.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (17114.0,16217.0)
Center      ( 8557.0, 8108.5)
Band 1 Block=17114x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Manually setting the max value does not change the appearance of the image? The higher the max value is, the darker the picture gets.

Comment: You're right. I can set the max values manually via QGIS and that does fix the image. But I'm not sure why the scale changes during reprojection? How can I ensure that the pixel scale remains the same after reprojection via `gdalwarp`?

Comment: I once met a similar issue with aerial images which were much darker that they used to be from the original software. It was related to a bit-encoding; the hardware+software manufacturer of the acquisition device encoded the image in 12 bits, and I asked a classical GIS software, which at that time could only opened 8-bit imagery (and many 16-bit, but definitely not 12), to open it. It was obviously not rendered as I expected. Just a thought...

Comment: Where are those high pixel values? Maybe there is a resampling bug. Or are the values all scaled to that new range?

Comment: @bugmenot123 How can I find that out?

Comment: Set the symbology to only show pixels >15000.

Comment: Ok so if I set min=0 and max=4454 in the reprojected raster it looks as expected. I set min=4454 and max=15561 to see what the extra pixels were and I got an all black square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with how QGIS was displaying the range of the raster. As stated in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58809/min-and-max-values-not-correctly-calculated-for-dem-using-qgis), QGIS, by default does not calculate the range of the entire dataset but estimates it instead. This can be seen in **Properties > Symbology > Band Rendering > Min/Max settings**. The default option for accuracy is **Estimate(faster)**. You need to set it to **Actual(slower)** to get the real max and min of the raster.

The true range of my original geotiff was **0 to 15561**. The 0 to 4454 was just the estimate. So my reprojection was showing the true range while the orignal was showing the estimated range. I was able to confirm this via loading the raster and looking at the array & via the following commands

```
gdal_translate -stats src.tiff dummy.tiff
gdalinfo dummy.tiff
```

However it's weird to me that if **Estimate** is the default option for QGIS then the reprojection should have also automatically been scaled to 0 to 4454 just like the original geotiff.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense to have *Estimate* as the default QGIS program setting.  I've submitted a feature request to allow the default to be set to *Actual*.  See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41305