# Reprojecting TIFF from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326 - Output Darkened

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp, rgb

I'm using QGIS to re-reference a batch of satImages from one CRS to another. I've got it to run and complete, that's fine. However, looking at the images pre-processing they are bright and vivid in their colour, after the processing they have darkened significantly and are difficult to see.

As I understand it, the high quality images have the usual RGB bands, but also have a 4th 'Alpha band' which appears to be getting fiddled with during the output processing.

How can this be prevented?

---

First image is the GDAL/QGIS output

Second image is the output viewed in QGIS

Third image is viewed along side other TIFFs in my application. Note the difference between the circled town on the right vs. the circled town on the left. This is the output of 'rearranging bands' and removing the 4th Alpha band. Slightly brighter but nothing on the 2nd Image within QGIS.

[image: GDAL output]

[image: Output viewed in QGIS]

[image: Output in my application]

Comment: how do you warp your pictures? can you maybe share a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: Show gdalinfo reports of the source image and the converted one.

Comment: Thanks @sn1ks and user30184, i've updated my post with a picture. Hope this helps and thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the settings of your new raster. As suggested here, it might be QGIS guessing the scale of your bands wrong.

- [Reprojecting raster changes pixel scale (makes it darker)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385650/reprojecting-raster-changes-pixel-scale-makes-it-darker)
- [Min and max values not correctly calculated for DEM using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58809/min-and-max-values-not-correctly-calculated-for-dem-using-qgis)